# Issue with installing Circuit-Python-GPS along with Blinka -- incorrect version of Python

Tags: python-3, circuitpython

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with nthe latest version of Raspbian (version 9). I have recently purchased the Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout for a project that assists Blind users around their environment using this GPS module. To use my GPS module, I need to install Circuit-Python along with Blinka libraries to assist the module. I keep getting an error message when I run the following code in the terminal:

$ sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython=gps

The error pertains to having the incorrect version of Python installed. Originally my main verse ion of Python was version 3.5, and Circuit Python requires 3.6 and above. So I installed version 3.8 to my Pi.
The problem now is that I still get the error message. I think it has something to do with having multiple versions of Python on my Pi(2.7,3.5, and 3.8). What should I do to make 3.8 my main Python version?

Note when I type:

$ python --version

into the terminal it says Python 3.8.0

Comment: Just install the current Raspberry Pi OS. Yours is 2 years old.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I've seen something on this tutorial I am following that mentions OS buster. If I get the current RPi OS will it have Python 3.6 or higher?

Comment: Current python3 is 3.7

Comment: Incidentally if your python -V says 3.8 you have done something wrong. This should be 2.7

Comment: Well I recently installed Python 3.8, before I did this the version was Python 3.5. I have 2.7 as well.

Comment: I am at the point where I could scrub everything and reinstall the current OS

Comment: My point is if you modified python to run python3 (as many incorrectly suggest) it is definitely wrong and likely to break other things. It isn't that hard to type python3!

Comment: `at the point where I could scrub everything and reinstall the current OS` yes - upgrading between major releases of Raspberry Pi OS isn't recommended unless you really know what you're doing

Comment: Did you happen to [read the instructions?](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/installing-circuitpython-on-raspberry-pi) All of your questions seem to be answered there.

Comment: @Seamus yes that is the tutorial I am following. I recently talked to a mentor for my project, and he assisted me with the project. For Python3 --version the result was 3.5.3, but when I just do Python --version I get 3.8.0. The problem for me arose, because I am new to this and entered things in the terminal incorrectly. Thank you guys for the help

Comment: Yes - Python is confusing because of the legacy issues - this leads to all sorts of dysfunction and confusion. Python aficionados will minimize that, but just between you and me: it's an atrocious, ugly hack. Watch this space... someone will comment by way of excusing the Python maintainers :)   Oh, BTW - [when you accept someone's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), it's expected that you will also "upvote" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things to try:

1. What do you get if you type `python3 --version`? I'm thinking it's possible `python3`/`pip3` is mapped to python 3.5 and `python`/`pip` is mapped to 3.8.
2. Since we know the version of typing `python` is 3.8, you could just use `pip` which should use the same version.
3. When you un the script, are you using `sudo`? If not, the module should be installed without the sudo command.
4. I'm not sure if you typed it with the `=` sign or if that was just a typo on stack exchange, but it should be `sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-gps`.
5. You could try using `python -m pip` in place of `pip3`